# Change order of elements in a Webform Variant

Tags: webforms

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to change the order of elements in a webform variant.

Using a very simple example form with two elements, I created a new variant and then overrode the "Elements" yaml two different ways, neither which changed the order of the elements on the form.

First, I simply switched the order of the elements in the yml, which didn't change anything. Second, I added a `#weight` attribute to each element with different values - this had no effect as well.

Is it possible to change the order of elements in a variant?

thanks,
-mike

Answer (score 1):

Your need to reorder elements makes sense. The #weight attribute is currently ignored because it can cause unpredictable rendering. I don't think a Variant can reorder elements without patching the webform module.

Answer (score 0):

Albeit brute-force, theoretically you might be able to do this via a custom variant plugin type.

```
class MyVariant extends WebformVariantBase {
  // ...
  // ...

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function applyVariant() {
    $webform = $this->getWebform();
    $elements = $webform->getElementsDecoded();

    $element_to_move = $elements['element_to_move'];
    $new_position = array_search('element_to_insert_after', array_keys($elements), TRUE);
    $before = array_slice($elements, 0, $new_position);
    $after = array_slice($elements, $new_position, count($elements) - $new_position);
    $new_elements = $before + ['element_to_move' => $element_to_move] + $after;
    $webform->setElements($new_elements);

    return TRUE;
  }
}
```